# WildFly 14: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to class io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, web-deployment

Trying to deploy a Spring Boot application to WildFly 14 I get the following error:

> {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"application_name\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to class io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.application_name.war' @56a6a8b7; io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'io.undertow.websocket@2.0.13.Final' @59ba0563)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to class io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.application_name.war' @56a6a8b7; io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'io.undertow.websocket@2.0.13.Final' @59ba0563)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to class io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.application_name.war' @56a6a8b7; io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer is in unnamed module of loader 'io.undertow.websocket@2.0.13.Final' @59ba0563)"}}

I have already tried everything that I could find in stackoverflow or other blogs, forums etc. but with no luck. I endeded up with the following pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.foo.application_name</groupId>
<artifactId>application_name</artifactId>
<version>xxx</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId> org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId> spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- update Hibernate dependency on Javassist to 3.23.1 for Java 11 compatibility -->
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- update Mockito dependency for Java 11 compatibility -->
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Could somebody please check my pom.xml and tell what am I missing?

Comment: Seems good to me as you already excluded all the tomcat stuff as mentioned in https://github.com/joshlong/boot-examples/issues/2 . Did you try to unzip the WAR and verify there is no tomcat stuff in the lib?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It seems that the created war file indeed contains the respective tomcat files, despite the fact that I have excluded them. There must be something wrong with the IntelliJ IDEA maven plugin or some setting or something.

Comment: you can try to build the WAR directly from command line , something likes `mvn clean package` to ensure that IDE will not mess up with the Maven build process

Comment: I have just built the war file from a windows intellij IDEA installation and everything worked. Obviously something is wrong with my Ubuntu Intellij IDEA setup or there is a bug (similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87868)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make you spring-boot-starter-underow as scope = provided. This counts for any other web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying to an external servlet container or application server, they should either exclude the built-in container (if you'll only deploy it as a war) or mark it as provided (if you want the war to be executable as well). This is described in the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

The project you show has an error. You are trying to use Undertow, but you have not excluded Tomcat from spring-boot-starter-jersey. If you are deploying on JBoss, they should also mark the spring-boot-starter-undertow dependency as provided or exclude it as well.